# BigQuery load compressed data from Cloud Storage

Tags: gzip, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, avro

I have a lot of *.gz files in my Google Cloud Storage.
I want to load those data to BigQuery.
I've tried to execute

```
bq load --source_format=AVRO projectId:dataset.table gs://bucket/*.gz
```

But received error

```
The Apache Avro library failed to parse file gs://bucket/f92d8ae3-6eba-4e35-9fc0-b8f31b4b9881-part-r-00004.gz.
```

Is it possible to upload compressed data to BigQuery? What is the best pracrise for those problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compressed Avro files are not supported ...
See more in [Avro format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-formats#avro_format)